# Why GridLines Option fail with Show?

Tags: plotting

As stated in the title: I am trying to find the reason on the documentation, but maybe I am not able yet to understand it (recently new user). Can anybody tell me why `GridLines`doesn't work if placed as in the following example, but it does if placed out?

```
 Show[ListLogLogPlot[Table[i, {i, 0, 2}], Joined -> True], 
 GridLines -> All] (*not working*)


 Show[ListLogLogPlot[Table[i, {i, 0, 2}],  GridLines -> All,Joined -> True]] 
 (*working*)
```

Comment: Where is `GridLines -> All` documented?

Comment: There are examples such as `DateListPlot[mvar, GridLines -> {All, None}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"HP", "IBM"}]`  in [TimeSeriesAggregate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesAggregate.html), for instance, or `DensityPlot[Sin[x + y^2], {x, 0.1, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 < x^2 + y^2 < 5], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {2^Range[-5, 2], Automatic}}, 
 GridLines -> All]` in [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html)

Comment: `Automatic` instead of `All`? `Show[ListLogLogPlot[Table[i, {i, 0, 2}], Joined -> True], 
 GridLines -> Automatic] ` does work, AND it is documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `Show` and `ListLogLogPlot` accept graphics options so `GridLines` can be an option for both. The **observed**(no sources other than myself) reason it works when invoked inside the `ListLogLogPlot` function and not within the `Show` function is the following:

- `GridLines -> All` produces grids intersecting all ticks generated automatically on all axes (i.e. when `Ticks -> Automatic`)
- `Show` seems to be oblivious to the number or location of ticks of the different graphics objects passed to it as inputs so it doesn't understand you when you tell it to put a grid on `All` ticks. However, `GridLines -> Automatic` as a `Show` option will give you gridlines at positions different than your `ListLogLogPlot` `Automatic` ticks
- `ListLogLogPlot` will generate a figure whose `Automatic` ticks is known to it and therefore is able to understand what `GridLines -> All` means

```
Show[ListLogLogPlot[Table[i, {i, 0, 2}], Joined -> True], 
 GridLines -> Automatic] 

Show[ListLogLogPlot[Table[i, {i, 0, 2}], GridLines -> All, 
  Joined -> True]]
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3gT1.png)

Comment: so do you believe it is always better to state `GridLines` inside `Plot` function rather than `Show` (also, if I have many functions inside `Show`, maybe it is good to put `GridLines` in one of those?)

Comment: I would say that it is always better to style ticks and Gridlines in one of the plots instead of Show. If you have many plots inside of Show, format the Gridlines in 1 of the plots (possibly the one covering the bigger range) only.

Comment: Is this an observation or are there any sources you could link?

Comment: @Kuba I re-edited the answer so that it is clear that those are **observed** behaviors. Actually, there is no explanation of what `GridLines -> All` actually does in the Mathematica documentation.

Comment: @AssaadMrad Thanks for clarification.